# Custom Icon Orientation Anchor Point Flutter Google Map

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I use this code to create a custom icon for Flutter Google Map marker

```
createMarker(){
    final MarkerId markerId = getMarkerId();
      markers[markerId] = Marker(
        rotation: driverLocation.orientation,
        markerId: markerId,
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(await getBytesFromAsset('assets/icons/taxi-icon.png', 50);),
        position: position.toLatLng(),
      );
}
 Future<Uint8List> getBytesFromAsset(String path, int width) async {
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(path);
    ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List(), targetWidth: width);
    ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
    return (await fi.image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png)).buffer.asUint8List();
  }
```

It works fine but I played around with the orientation, I discovered that the anchor point of the marker seems to be on the top edge of the image, not in its center. How to change the anchor point to the center of the image ?

Comment: Interestingly, for me, the anchor point is the bottom center.

Answer (score 5):

Try to add anchor parameter to the marker.

```
Marker(
   ...
   anchor: const Offset(0.5, 0.5)
);
```

Default:

```
anchor: const Offset(0.5, 1.0)
```

To set anchor point to the center of icon:

```
anchor: const Offset(0.5, 0.5)
```

To set anchor point to the top-left corner of icon:

```
anchor: const Offset(0.0, 0.0)
```

To set anchor point to the bottom-right corner of icon:

```
anchor: const Offset(1.0, 1.0)
```